Prove a Result about Optimization and Exponential Distribution: Intuitive but Challenging
Let $v=(v_1,v_2,...v_N)$ be a random vector with $N$ elements.

$v_i \perp v_j$ for any $i\neq j$.
For each $i$, the CDF of $v_i$ is: $F_i(v_i)=1-e^{-(v_i-a_i)/\theta}$, where $v_i\in [a_i,\infty)$.
Assume $0<\theta<a_1<a_2<...<a_N$ and $c>0$.
Let $x(v)=(x_1(v),x_2(v)...x_N(v))$ be the solution of the following problem
\begin{equation}
\max_{x(v)} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i (v_i-\theta- cx_i)
\end{equation} subject to $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\leq1$. Since $v$ is random, $x(v)$ is also a random vector.

Prove: $\mathbb{E}(x_N)-\mathbb{E}(x_1)$ is a decreasing function of $c$.
My attempts:

This result is quite intuitive and I've verified using MATLAB for different parameters.
If $N=2$, this can be proved.
The solution for each $x_i$ is the following: if $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{v_i-\theta}{2c}\leq1$, then $x_i=\frac{v_i-\theta}{2c}$; if $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{v_i-\theta}{2c}>1$, then $x_i=\frac{[v_i-\theta-\lambda(v)]^+}{2c}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i=1$ for some Lagrange multiplier $\lambda(v)>0$. Note that $\lambda$ is symmetric, i.e., $\lambda(v_i,v_j,v_{-{i,j}})$=$\lambda(v_j,v_i,v_{-{i,j}})$ for all $i\neq j$.
I think the challenge is the $[\quad]^+$ sign in the solution of $x_i$, if we remove this, the result is obviuosly true. But the $[\quad]^+$ sign makes it messy.
Maybe Mathematical Induction is useful, I've tried, but still didn't prove it.


Should the expectation be removed from the statement of the optimization problem? That is, $x(v) = \arg\max_x \sum_i x_i (v_i - \theta - cx_i)$ subject to the inequality constraints?

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Can you please elaborate a bit more on your previous attempts to answer your question? What have you tried before? Put that in your post, and can you try to make it so others can benefit from your question as well? Simply posting your question to get an answer, unfortunately, does not look good on here, as I've had the annoying experience of learning. I don't want the same to happen to you.

@angryavian,  thanks a lot, I've updated the question. In this question, $x(v)$ is also a random vector.

@YourLordJoyBoy, thanks a lot for the suggestions, I've updated the question, and also explained what I've done to solve it and what might work. Your suggestion that makes others benefit from the question is very important, thank you!

Of course. I had to learn it myself so I'm glad I could help someone else with the same issue instead of going through what I had to.
